# what is the function of prandom_seed_state?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

THIS FUNC is in  linux-4.16.12\include\linux\random.h

```
static inline u32 __seed(u32 x, u32 m)
{
    return (x < m) ? x + m : x;
}

static inline void prandom_seed_state(struct rnd_state *state, u64 seed)
{
    u32 i = (seed >> 32) ^ (seed << 10) ^ seed;

    state->s1 = __seed(i,   2U);
    state->s2 = __seed(i,   8U);
    state->s3 = __seed(i,  16U);
    state->s4 = __seed(i, 128U);
}
```

It sames like a random function, but  i am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The function generates a four-element state vector from a 64-bit seed value, by recombining the 64 bits into a 32-bit value. All four elements in the state vector are set to this same value, but the algorithm used requires that the elements of the state vector not have too many leading zeros.

This requirement is explained in the `prandom_u32()` implementation code in `lib/random32.c` [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/lib/random32.c#L22).

The `prandom_seed_state()` function is not itself a pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) -- that's `prandom_u32()` -- but it is required to initialize the state of the PRNG. (In practice, each thread has its own pseudorandom state, to avoid unnecessary synchronization.)